# R dplyr with multiple columns with same stem name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data columns that I need to set to NA whenever a corresponding column is >0.

I can do this with mutate and the names of the two columns, but I want a scoped version where I create the name of the corresponding column from the name of the 1st column

```
(x<-data.frame(x1=(1:4),map.x1=c(0,0,7,0),x2=c(2,2,2,2),map.x2=c(0,7,0,0)))

mutate(x, x1=ifelse(map.x1>0, NA, x1))

mutate_at(x, vars(starts_with("x")), function(v) { 
  m.name <- paste0("map.", deparse(substitute(v)))
  ifelse(get(m.name)>0, NA, v)
  )
}
```

I can see ifelse() is unhappy because it wants the 1st argument to be an object, and I have given an expression.

I could not find a way. I even wondered if there was some way to avoid the function(v) and use (.) in paste0() or get()

I also am considering reshaping so I can do one mutate. What is the best practice here?

Comment: There is a mess in function's parentheses and brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution without reshaping the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

custom_mutate <- function(df, v){
  v <- enquo(v)
  map.v <- paste0("map.", quo_name(v))

  df %>%
    mutate(UQE(v) := ifelse((!!sym(map.v)) > 0, NA, (!!v))) %>% 
    pull(UQE(v))
}

mutate_at(x, vars(starts_with("x")), funs(custom_mutate(df = x, v = .)))

#   x1 map.x1 x2 map.x2
# 1  1      0  2      0
# 2  2      0 NA      7
# 3 NA      7  2      0
# 4  4      0  2      0
```

The function in the `mutate_at` call is only applied to the columns and not to the whole dataframe. Therefore you have to explicitly tell the function where to look for your `map.x1` column.
To get the name from the column you're working with, first you need to use `enquo` to turn `v` in a `quosure`. Then you can use `quo_name` to construct the `map.`-name. In the following `mutate` call it is important that you tell `dplyr`, that `v` is a quosure (therefore the `UQE` wrapped around it, which is similar to the `!!` in front of it in the `FALSE`-part of the `ifelse` statement).
For the `map.x1` column you have to use the `sym`-function from the `rlang`-package to get the bare name (without quotations) and then again use the `!!` to tell `dplyr` to take this as a column name.

I trief to explain my solution, being not to technical. For a great explanation of how to programm with dplyr see here: [Programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Thanks @kath, I was hoping a answer without reshape would be offered. I do have to read this carefully because I have not worked with the quosure before (just seen it in video). It may turn out reshape is more "readable" but this is what I wanted to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get the output you want. No need to write a custom function. Reshaping the file should be sufficient.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(stats)

# creating dataframe with proper names
x <-
  tibble::as_data_frame(cbind(
    x_1 = c(1:4),
    map.x_1 = c(0, 0, 7, 0),
    x_2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
    map.x_2 = c(0, 7, 0, 0)
  )) %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(df = ., var = 'id')

# converting to long format
x_long <- stats::reshape(
  as.data.frame(x),
  timevar = "level",
  varying = dput(as.character(as.vector(names(
    x[, base::grep("^x|^map", names(x))]
  )))),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = c("id"),
  sep = "_"
)
#> c("x_1", "map.x_1", "x_2", "map.x_2")

# converting the dataframe based on condition
x_long %>%
  group_by(.data = ., level) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(.data = .,
                x = base::ifelse(test = map.x > 0,
                                 yes = NA,
                                 no = x))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   level [2]
#>   id    level     x map.x
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1      1.00  1.00  0   
#> 2 2      1.00  2.00  0   
#> 3 3      1.00 NA     7.00
#> 4 4      1.00  4.00  0   
#> 5 1      2.00  2.00  0   
#> 6 2      2.00 NA     7.00
#> 7 3      2.00  2.00  0   
#> 8 4      2.00  2.00  0
```

Created on 2018-02-14 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: thanks @Indrajeet, I think I am going to reshape. It was an option I had considered. Great to have some code worked out.

Comment: @D.Bontempo Cool, in that case please accept the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that this thread will be closed.

Comment: thanks again, I was not savvy to closing threads. I will wait a little while, because the issue of dplyr with two dynamic column names is still of interest. If nobody answers soon, I will close this thread, and consider a more generic one in the future.